# Google Analytics shows many pages/visit and only a few visits

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to use page level custom variables but I'm getting weird results.

Per each value of the variable, the custom variables report shows only a few visits (1-3), but many pages per visit (hundreds).

My tracking code is as follows:

```
_gaq.push(['my_tracker._setCustomVar', 1, 'Name', params['name'], 3]);
_gaq.push(['my_tracker._trackPageview']);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post in your entire Google Analytics tracking?  Usually there is a lot more that `_setCustomVar` and `_trackPageview`.  There has to be a `_setAccount` as well, and there may be others.

Comment: sure. I have a _gaq.push(['my_tracker._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX']); as part of the standard GA tracking code snippet before that, but nothing else.